# "Problem description" to look like abstract

Tags: formatting, environments, abstract

I would like to have my "Problem Description" to have the same look/layout as abstract.
Any way I can "clone" the the abstract command?

preamble:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,b5paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}
```

Comment: don't use explicitly the `pdftex` option; the packages needing it are usually able to provide it implicitly.

Comment: @egreg Ok, uni. template..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\newenvironment{problemdesc}
  {\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Problem Description}%
   \begin{abstract}}
  {\end{abstract}}
```

In this way you can also use the normal `abstract` environment.

If many kinds of this generalized abstract environment are needed, one can do the following

```
\newenvironment{genabstract}[1][]
  {\ifx\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
     % no optional argument
   \else
     % provide the desired title
     \renewcommand{\abstractname}{#1}%
   \fi
   \begin{abstract}}
  {\end{abstract}}
```

The calls can then be

```
\begin{genabstract}
<regular abstract>
\end{genabstract}

\begin{genabstract}[Problem Description]
<problem description>
\end{genabstract}
```

Don't feed `\abstractname` as the optional argument, as this would cause infinite recursion (it would be possible to avoid this, but it seems overkill).

Comment: Even better would be to put `\renewvommand{\abstractname}{Abstract}` in the endcode I think? Or is there  reason this would not work?

Comment: @romeovs: every environment forms a group, so that `\renewcommand` would have no effect, because the "end part" is evaluated before the group ends.

Comment: hmm, okay don't know about groups. Just seemed logical to change it back. You mean that it will only be changed inside the group then?

Comment: @romeovs: the redefinition of `\abstractname` in the "begin part" will be undone anyway when the environment ends, because it's made inside a group.

Comment: okay, all I needed to know!

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[english]{report}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}
\begin{document}

{\renewcommand\abstractname{Problem Description}%
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}%
}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}%

\blindtext
\end{document}
```